# Fireabase CLI Stop reuploading all function folder?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

How can I make Firebase CLI to not re-upload all the files located in the function directory ?

I have really slow internet connection and modifying an minor bug in function code makes the whole folder/directory to re-upload which `40MB` which is taking 25 minutes to upload.
This is not bearable for every code change that I make and can't use emulator because I am trying to learn storage changes function.

How can I speed up this process ?

Answer (score 1):

You can deploy function which you have changed by this command

```
$ firebase deploy --only functions:YOUR_FUNCTION_NAME
```

Comment: Thank you for your time.brother i am already using this still the CLI reuploads the whole folder

Comment: I have one more option for you. Log in into google.cloud.console -> GO to the Cloud function -> Edit your function -> deploy. It'll take less than a minute to deploy your changes.

Comment: Yes you can update the function directly from browser. Please follow the steps:
1) Log in into https://cloud.google.com/functions
2) Go to console.
3) Open the side bar there you'll find Cloud function in a "Compute section"
4) By clicking on Cloud function you'll be redirected to the list of all your function.

Comment: Can't use inline editor as my source size is bigger than 512kb and its 40MB however thank you for the information it helped me in other way.

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase CLI will always upload the entire contents of the functions folder, except for node_modules, which will be rebuilt by Cloud Functions using your package.json.  There is no way to change this behavior.

You should look into your options to test locally, so you don't have to go through the process of deploying each time you want to test a change.

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-shell